# DialogFlow - User Share Location from Messenger Facebook

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es

I am working on a project that the user must share their location from the Facebook Messenger channel

As written below, Facebook no longer uses the option to Share location in quick responses.

I think the best option would be to use the google maps API, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has removed this feature, the Dialogflow docs you are looking at appear to simply not be up-to-date in this regard.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies#locations:

> On July 29, 2019 we deprecated the location button type for V4.0 and will be removing it for all versions on October 29, 2019
>
> During F8 2019, we announced our plans to launch a [lighter, better and simpler Messenger](https://messengernews.fb.com/2019/04/30/messenger-at-f8-2019-announcing-a-faster-lighter-messenger-designed-to-build-closer-connections/) designed to build closer connections between people and businesses.
>
> Starting August 15, 2019, updated versions of the Messenger app will no longer render Location quick reply. We recommend businesses ask for zip code and address information within the thread. While we are sunsetting the existing version of Share Location, in the coming months we will be introducing new ways for people to communicate their location to businesses in more valuable ways. Refer to [June 10, 2019 Announcement](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog/#20190610).